# List of all available servers in Network c# - displayed only one, not many

Tags: c#, networking, service, installation, server

I am using `SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()` for retrieving servername to connected in LAN.

This code working for others, but for myself only shows one server name only; not all server name.

Is there anything enable the service or installed something on my Laptop?

Please help me!

Comment: maybe you don't have sufficient permissions?

Comment: How to get permissions for accessing all networks?

Comment: you don't need such permissions!

Comment: listing few servers for me only, But for others listing much servers.. how to fix these issue?
Why i do not need permissions. then how to ascess?